# Python Calculate Character Statistics

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I modify the attached program to print letter statistics in the form like

a = 3

b = 2

c = 1

and eliminating the use of 'z" to mark end of line, instead of \r.

```
def getLetIndex(pline, k):
    return pline[k]

print("work with lists or arrays")
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
k=0
while k < 26:
    list[k]=0
    k +=1
print("list[1]=", list[1])

mline=input("enter a sentence=>")
print("you have entered=", mline)
k=0
while k < 26:
    k+= 1
    oneChar = getLetIndex(mline, k)
    if oneChar == 'z':
        break
    num1 = ord(oneChar)
    print("char=", oneChar, "char-num=", num1)
    if num1 != 32:                  # not space
        list[num1-97+1] += 1
print("letter statistics are below")
k=0
while k < 26:
    print(list[k])
    k +=1
print("list[1]=", list[1])
```

Comment: In your final while loop, change `print(list[k])` to `print("{} = {}".format(chr(97+k), list[k]))`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]
k=0
while k < 26:
    list[k]=0
    k +=1
print("list[1]=", list[1])
```

will just produce a list with 26 elements, all with the value of `0`

So you can replace thiw with:

```
list = [0] * 26
```

However it is not really necessary to build this list (as you can see later). Besides you should not use the word `list` as a variable name.

You also do the following:

```
while k < 26:
    k+= 1
    oneChar = getLetIndex(mline, k)
    if oneChar == 'z':
        break
    num1 = ord(oneChar)
    print("char=", oneChar, "char-num=", num1)
    if num1 != 32:                  # not space
        list[num1-97+1] += 1
```

This is obvious that you want to loop through 26 times, and stop when encountering an end of line character, which is set to `z` by your code. You don't have to do that either. And the other limitation of this is, what would happen if the sentence entered is more than 26 characters ?

From this if `num1 != 32:` I believe you do not want to count spaces.
And lets use the `Counter` from `collections`

This code:

```
mline=input("enter a sentence=>")
print("you have entered=", mline)
k=0
while k < 26:
    k+= 1
    oneChar = getLetIndex(mline, k)
    if oneChar == 'z':
        break
    num1 = ord(oneChar)
    print("char=", oneChar, "char-num=", num1)
    if num1 != 32:                  # not space
        list[num1-97+1] += 1
```

Will now become:

```
from collections import Counter

mline=input("enter a sentence=>")  
mline = mline.replace(" ","")             # this will get rid of spaces
c = Counter(mline)                        # create a counter object
for char, count in c.items():             # enumerate through the items
    print("{} = {}".format(char, count))  # print the result
```

Now this result is not sorted, but you get the idea.
You can now further experiment with the code, add additional print statements, or whatever else you like to do.

HTH.